# Updating column in a table based on the value from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have 2 tables :
EMP and TMP_EMP which are both identical.  I am using Oracle.

EMP:

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | ALLOWED  |
+----------+----------+
| 1-xx     |    0     |
| 2-xx     |    1     |
| 3-xx     |    0     |
| 4-xx     |    2     |
+----------+----------+
```

TMP_EMP:

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | ALLOWED  |
+----------+----------+
| 1-xx     |    0     |
| 2-xx     |    0     |
| 4-xx     |    0     |
| 5-xx     |    0     |
+----------+----------+
```

What I want to do is to update the the field ALLOWED in the TMP_EMP table and set it to the same value of ALLOWED in the EMP
table if the employee exist in both tables.
In short the final TMP_EMP table should look like this:

TMP_EMP:

```
+----------+----------+
| ID       | ALLOWED  |
+----------+----------+
| 1-xx     |    0     |
| 2-xx     |    1     |
| 4-xx     |    2     |
| 5-xx     |    0     |
+----------+----------+
```

I have written my sql update as follows :

```
update TMP_EMP
set ALLOWED = IC.ALLOWED
WHERE ID in (
SELECT IC.ID 
FROM TMP_EMP tmp, EMP IC 
where IC.ID LIKE decode(instr(tmp.ID,'-'),0,tmp.ID,substr(tmp.ID,0,instr(tmp.ID,'-')-1)) || '%');
```

But this is not working.  I would be really grateful for any  help here.  Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what the various IDs look like.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : the IDs are in the format y-xx.  Examples: 1-AB, 1-FD, 2-DW, 2-GF

Comment: you could use Merge for this

Comment: @Shruti : Can you show me an example pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE TMP_EMP t1
SET ALLOWED = (SELECT ALLOWED
               FROM EMP t2
               WHERE t2.ID LIKE DECODE(INSTR(t1.ID, '-'), 0, t1.ID,
                                       SUBSTR(t1.ID, 0, INSTR(t1.ID, '-')-1)) || '%')
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ALLOWED
               FROM EMP t2
               WHERE t2.ID LIKE DECODE(INSTR(t1.ID, '-'), 0, t1.ID,
                                       SUBSTR(t1.ID, 0, INSTR(t1.ID, '-')-1)) || '%')
```

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Comment: This does not work. I get the following error: SQL Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"  I am actually searching through the error.

Comment: Then your data has a problem.  You need to provide us with logic regarding what should happen should an ID match to multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

Not tried in oracle but i would use a CTE to do this.

```
;with tmp as (
    SELECT IC.ID 
    FROM TMP_EMP tmp, EMP IC 
    where IC.ID LIKE decode(instr(tmp.ID,'-'),0,tmp.ID,substr(tmp.ID,0,instr(tmp.ID,'-')-1)) || '%');
)
update te
set te.ALLOWED = tmp.ALLOWED
from TMP_EMP te
inner join tmp on tmp.ID = te.ID
```

Comment: Update joins are not possible in Oracle.

Comment: I'm an SQL Server kid...didn't know that..thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: Yeah, it's a major drawback of Oracle that we have to use really ugly queries for updating.